# Image does not draw but another image does.

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have a canvas that draws one image but doesn't draw another image of the same file type. Here's my code.

```
var context = document.getElementById('canv').getContext("2d");
        var vx = 0;
        var W = canv.width;
        var H = canv.height;

        var canvback = new Image();         
        canvback.src = "canvback.png";

        var vx = 0;
        var canvroad = new Image();
        canvroad.src = "canvroad.png";

        var car = new Image();
        car.src = "mooncrash.png";

        (function renderGame() {
            window.requestAnimationFrame(renderGame);

            context.clearRect(0, 0, W, H);


            context.drawImage(canvback, 0, 0);              
            context.drawImage(canvroad, vx, 465);               
            context.drawImage(canvroad, canvroad.width-Math.abs(vx), 465);


            if (Math.abs(vx) > canvroad.width) {
            vx = 0;
            }

            vx -= 2;
            context.drawImage(car, 500, 300);
        }());
```

but when I change mooncrash.png to car.png it doesn't draw. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you have `car.png` in your folder ?? Try to convert your image into `.jpg` in GIMP/PS/.. and then use it with `car.src = car.jpg`

Comment: yes they are both in the same folder.

Comment: When you open the console, do you get errors ?

Comment: 45Crazy%20Road%20Trip.html:64 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
 --------------------------------------
331Crazy%20Road%20Trip.html:63 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state.
 -------------------------------------
569Crazy Road Trip.html:64 Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to execute 'drawImage' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The HTMLImageElement provided is in the 'broken' state

Comment: Extending @Pleasure's answer, but are you sure is a valid PNG.  Some apps will open image irrespective of the extension.  Something like irfanview will tell you it is not a PNG, but a jpg, etc.  Also, try and just copy and paste mooncrash.png to car.png and see if it still loads, then you know if it is file or security or other.

Comment: sorry.. tried to split it up..

Comment: Usually you get broken state image when the file you want to access isn't there. It's that thing : http://www.underconsideration.com/brandnew/archives/google_broken_image_00_b_logo_detail.gif. Try @Anthony's suggestion, that would help a lot understanding your problem !

Comment: I renamed the mooncrash.png to car and it worked so guess it's just the file?